# ESXi vmware tools recognises CentOS 7 as CentOS 6

Tags: centos, virtualization, vmware-esxi

I am using vmware Remote Console (VMRC) to access a virtual machine running CentOS 7 with the included open-vm-tools 10309 which are recognised by the ESXi-host.

I am able to shutdown or restart the VM from within the guest system through vmware-tools commands, but after a while ESXi web client (HTML5), which I use to monitor everything, throws a weird warning about a misconfiguration of the guest system. It reads somewhat like:

```
Your guest OS is running CentOS 6, but the VM is configured for CentOS 7. > Actions
```

Which is pretty weird, since I can confirm I'm running CentOS 7 (1804 release).

It does not negatively influence the function of ESXi nor the VM, but it's unlogical behavior. Did someone experience the same or has any suggestions?

Comment: Update the web client or report the problem to VMware.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the [bug is in openvm-tools](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/311), which sees the "6." in "7.6.1810" and reports it as CentOS 6. It is reported in the [Red Hat Bugzilla as issue 1672087](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1672087). They do not want to apply the patch since it does not apply to Red Hat, and CentOS only builds Red Hat sources, so the fix will not show up there.

However, once you upgrade to CentOS 7.7 (which should be out soon) the problem should go away as there is no longer a "6." in the version strings...